# How can I use jQuery template inside groovy template in Play?

Tags: jquery, groovy, playframework, jquery-templates

How can I escape `${}` for a jQuery template inside a groovy template?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use {{ }}, {{= }} instead of the $ as this is used by groovy.

Comment: @James, if it solved the problem, you should accept the answer, by clicking the tick.